# Springboot 2.4.4 and awsPramstore

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, aws-parameter-store

```html
INFO  [2021-03-26 19:38:28.529] [main] i.a.c.p.AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator: Loading property from AWS Parameter Store with name: /document-upload/null/, optional: false
INFO  [2021-03-26 19:38:28.560] [main] i.a.c.p.AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator: Loading property from AWS Parameter Store with name: /document-upload/application_test/, optional: false
INFO  [2021-03-26 19:38:28.615] [main] i.a.c.p.AwsParamStorePropertySourceLocator: Loading property from AWS Parameter Store with name: /document-upload/application/, optional: false
DEBUG [2021-03-26 19:38:28.718] [main] i.a.c.p.AwsParamStorePropertySource: Populating property retrieved from AWS Parameter Store: authorization.clientId
DEBUG [2021-03-26 19:38:28.720] [main] i.a.c.p.AwsParamStorePropertySource: Populating property retrieved from AWS Parameter Store: authorization.clientSecret
DEBUG [2021-03-26 19:38:28.720] [main] i.a.c.p.AwsParamStorePropertySource: Populating property retrieved from AWS Parameter Store: management.metrics.export.influx.password
DEBUG [2021-03-26 19:38:28.720] [main] i.a.c.p.AwsParamStorePropertySource: Populating property retrieved from AWS Parameter Store: management.metrics.export.influx.user-name
DEBUG [2021-03-26 19:38:28.720] [main] i.a.c.p.AwsParamStorePropertySource: Populating property retrieved from AWS Parameter Store: scrive.token
DEBUG [2021-03-26 19:38:28.720] [main] i.a.c.p.AwsParamStorePropertySource: Populating property retrieved from AWS Parameter Store: spring.datasource.password
DEBUG [2021-03-26 19:38:28.720] [main] i.a.c.p.AwsParamStorePropertySource: Populating property retrieved from AWS Parameter Store: spring.datasource.username
INFO  [2021-03-26 19:38:28.721] [main] o.s.c.b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration: Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-/document-upload/null_test/'}, BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-/document-upload/null/'}, BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-/document-upload/application_test/'}, BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-/document-upload/application/'}]
INFO  [2021-03-26 19:38:28.837] [main] c.i.d.DocumentUploadApplication: The following profiles are active: test
WARN  [2021-03-26 19:38:32.413] [main] o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'aws.paramstore-io.awspring.cloud.paramstore.AwsParamStoreProperties' available
INFO  [2021-03-26 19:38:32.470] [main] o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
ERROR [2021-03-26 19:38:32.570] [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
A component required a bean named 'aws.paramstore-io.awspring.cloud.paramstore.AwsParamStoreProperties' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean named 'aws.paramstore-io.awspring.cloud.paramstore.AwsParamStoreProperties' in your configuration.
About Support File a Bug Documentation Privacy Policy
```

Why is it asking me for AwsParamStoreProperties.
In my pom i have only added dep to spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config

following https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.3.0-RC1/reference/html/index.html
sec 3.2

Comment: This happens when i deply to aws, when i try to run locally i can see that it goes into that AwsParamStoreProperties when i debug but since i don't have everything setup locally it crashes locally when it can't access ssm aws prameterstore. Bean should be created on aws also if it is being created locally.

Answer (score 0):

Please wait for sometime. The PR to address this is underway: https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/pull/102